# Prove that successive differences between square roots of integers decreases without using limits or derivatives

Tags: discrete-mathematics, alternative-proof

I have been trying to prove that $$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1}$$

for ALL $n = 1,2,3,...$ without success.

A similar question has been asked here [Why does the difference in square roots of two consecutive integers gets smaller as n grows?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770009/why-does-the-difference-in-square-roots-of-two-consecutive-integers-gets-smaller). However, the answers are either intuitive i.e. not rigorous, or use limits/derivatives.

My problem with using limits is that it only tells you this will *eventually* be true. Can we show **rigorously** that this is true for all $n = 1,2,3,...$ by just using algebra and basic proof methods?

Comment: Did you see AndrewLi's comment beneath that post? It gives the best explanation imo.

Comment: @MyMolecules I did. It's a nice explanation for intuition but it's not a proof.

Comment: Did you check *all* answers to the other question? There are at least two which do not use limits, derivatives, or intuition. – And if you think that an answer is unclear: you have sufficient reputation to leave a comment and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers in the link are sufficient, since the identity

$$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$$ immediately implies
$$\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1}},$$ and since $$\sqrt{n+2} > \sqrt{n},$$ it follows that
$$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2} + \sqrt{n+1}} = \sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+1}.$$

I don't know why you think this is not rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

Just square that!

$$(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt n)^2 = 2n+2+2\sqrt{n^2+2n} < 2n+2+2\sqrt{n^2+2n+1} = 4n+4 = (2\sqrt{n+1})^2$$
$$\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt n < 2\sqrt{n+1}$$
Some steps are left, but they are obvious.